# OrientDB - Import from an RDBMS (sql server)

Tags: jdbc, orientdb, orientdb-etl

How I would go about loading data from and SQL database where the table name is the node class, columns are the attributes of the node class and the rows in the table are individual instances of that node class?

I have had a look on the OrientDB website for help and the relevant page wasn't not very helpful

Thanks,

Bikrum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is use OrientDB Teleporter.

Teleporter is an automatic tool that connects to the JDBC source (the relational database), analyzes the db schema, creates a corresponding graph schema (eg. vertex classes for tables, edge classes for forieign keys or join tables ) and then copies all the data to OrientDB.

There is a visual tool that lets you fine tune all the details of the migration, that is included in OrientDB Studio, so it's in the bundle.

Since v 2.2.25 it's available in the Community Edition

From Studio login page just click on the RDBMS button (top right of the login form) and follow the guided steps.

Here is a reference to the docs: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Studio-Teleporter.html

Comment: Thanks for the help Luigi. I tried this and it is not available and says i need enterprise edition even though i am on version 2.2.21

Comment: Try latest 2.2.26, Teleporter is now in bundle with the CE